# Is this a way to debate?

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-gitin

[Gittin 20a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.20a.7?lang=bi&lang2=en):

> Rav Ḥisda said: I am able to invalidate all the bills of divorce in the world...  Rava said to him: What is the reason that you could invalidate them?

I would expect that [Rav Ḥisda](https://www.sefaria.org/topics/rav-chisda) would be allowed to present his argument.

Instead we get [*Rava*](https://www.sefaria.org/topics/rava) (from the *next* generation) propose and reject a couple of possible approaches.

Why wasn't Rav Chisda allowed to speak? What am I missing?

Comment: It might have been stated as a challenge, to test his students' knowledge and reasoning.

Comment: Hard to find a source for my answer, but based on experience, this is what is going on. In Rava's day, there was a record of Rav Chisda's statement, but there was a lack of clarity in what was the reasoning (either a debate about it, or it was just missing). Rava is therefore demonstrating the reasoning by laying out a pilpul, thus resolving the ambiguity and teaching the halacha.